# Issue with kernel boot [OVH SERVER]

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, openvz

Trying to install OpenVZ kernel on Centos 6.3, Yes my kernel is installed i can see it in the /boot folder, yes it is Rhel6 and yes it is all up to date, i checked this with yum update.

My issue comes when i reboot my server with that kernel set as the default, it doesn't load, below i shall put a copy of my grub.conf file and my menu.lst file.

Grub.conf:

default=0
timeout=5

title vzkernel (2.6.32-042stab057.1)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab057.1 ro root=/dev/sda1
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-042stab057.1.img

title linux centos6_64
kernel /boot/bzImage-3.2.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
root (hd0,0)

Now i shall paste in Menu.lst;

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE: You have a /boot partition. This means that
# all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
# root (hd0,0)
# kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_stock-lv_root
# initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Linux OpenVZ (vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab057.1)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab057.1 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_stock-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_stock/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_stock/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=l$
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-042stab057.1.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/bzImage-3.2.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_stock-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_stock/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_stock/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFO$
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.img
# dummy text
```

Somebody mentioned something about OVH having added a script which changes the kernel settings or something, and suggested that we either remove the script or reinstall using a VNC, but we don't know how to go about doing either of these?

Really would be great if you guys could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grub.conf` and `menu.lst` should be exactly the same file, with one symlinked to the other (for backward compatibility). You seem to have two different files.

From a live CentOS system as seen after installation:

```
-rw-------. 1 root root   1618 Oct 15 17:19 grub.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     11 Sep 21 11:44 menu.lst -> ./grub.conf
```

Comment: That did not resolve anything, it just done the same thing, doesn't even show a response from the server.